# PHP SoapClient get: ServerCan't find bundle for base name

Tags: java, php, exception, locale

I working with PHP SoapClient and get error.

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://example.org/site-service/webservice/DataProvider?wsdl", array('trace' => TRUE));

$client->modifyData($data);
(or $client->modifyData(), or $client->saveStudents)

var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
var_dump($client->__getLastResponse());
```

Always get exception:

> ServerCan't find bundle for base name i18.exceptions, locale lt

The server administrator said that the problem on my PHP server.

I found online solutions only for Java.  But I can not access to Java.

Please help.
P.s. Sorry, for my poor English.

Comment: If this is what you get from __getLastResponse() then this is SERVER side exception, not client. It seems like soap server is write in JAVA. You as clinet can't do anything unless you have an access to server you are trying to connect with. So I think you should talk to server admin again, but try to connect through SoapUI first to make sure in 100%.

Comment: Thank you. SoapUI helped me. My error....